# WebView scrolls itself

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uitextfield, contentoffset

I've got a UITextField added as a subview to a UIWebView that acts as an address bar for a browser. But it's behaving rather strangely, because when the field begins editing the webView automatically scrolls itself to about (-40, 0) and I can't figure out why. I've already tried calling [webView setContentOffset] to counteract this behavior, but that doesn't work for some reason (yes I have the delegate connected). Am I missing something?

Comment: perhaps something to do with the keyboard firstResponder stuff? (Naive guess)

Comment: Your code would be suuuuper helpful

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have set the delegates for the textfield too, and in delegate method

`- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string`

, reset the webview content

```
[webView setContentOffset]
```

I hope this will serve you better.